# Php Session Not Working When I Switched Host To Bluehost

Tags: php, session, bluehost

I am having issues with sessions being generated since I move my site to Bluehost. The project works perfectly on local Wampserver and on another host I tried. But since I uploaded to Bluehost, Sessions does not work. I don't seem to get it. I tried some of the guides i read through several research from multiple queries, and added the following codes to my config file:

```
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
session_start();
```

When I run this, a folder with the name "session" was created and I could see random keys generated in the folder, meaning that session was actually created. But the problem I'm having now is that I can't sign in to my protected files.

Please I need help on how to go about this. Could there be some kind of permissions required to enable sessions to work on Bluehost? Are there cache/tools I need to disable/enable to make this work?

I ran the following code to check for errors, but no result was queried.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

INSERT, SELECT, even UPDATE works perfect, but not SESSION. I have contacted there support team, but no positive help was offered. I sincerely appreciate anyone who could assist me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude.

Comment: see what happens when you change the session dir/files permission to 775, then login and see if that works, it thats the case it must be the permissions

Comment: If it was an issue with write permissions in the session storage dir, then properly enabled error reporting should give you some feedback on that. Can you try and enable it globally, from within the hosting panel, instead of trying to set it at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Look like issue with session directory permission
can you try this

```
ini_set('session.save_path', sys_get_temp_dir());
```

Comment: This is _not_ good advice, especially not on shared hosting. You don’t want to share your session storage directory with all other users on the system.